# Laravel if route condition not met then ignore

Tags: laravel

I have the following 2 routes:

```
Route::get('/{category}/{slug?}',  [CategoryController::class, 'index'])->name('category.index')->where('slug', 'trending|subtitled|feature');
```

This route

```
Route::get('/cookies-policy',  [PageController::class, 'cookiesPolicy'])->name('cookiesPolicy');
```

When i try to access the second route, the first route controller is accessed instead.

How do i add a condition to the first route, that if the first segment isn't `trending`,`subtitled` or `feature` then ignore?  I thought i accomplished this with: `->where('slug', 'trending|subtitled|feature')`

Comment: change the order of those 2 routes ... and your where condition would be on the category parameter not the slug parameter if you are talking about the 'first segment'

Comment: tried that but then the category route didn't work.  `cookies-policy` isn't in `trending,subtitled or feature` so it shouldn't match the category segment

Comment: if you adjust the route order then the second route would match for that exact path instead of the first route you have shown ... and you don't have your where condition on the category segment you put it on the slug segment ... `where('slug', ...)` means the slug parameter not the category parameter

Comment: Thanks, i added where condition for category segment, ad is now working correctly.

Comment: You need to change the route order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to adjust your `where` to be assigning the pattern to the `category` route parameter not the `slug` parameter:

```
->where('category', ...);
```